# Which font is the one used for the Euro 2012 Logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I need to know which font is used (or another similar one) for the UEFA Euro 2012 Logo?

[image]

[UEFA Euro 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9xMt.jpg)

Comment: Which part? the Euro the 2012 or the Poland-Ukraine bit - they are all different (by the looks of things)

Comment: Just the POLAND - UKRAINE part is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year looks to me like Century Gothic but the EURO part looks custom or maybe edited.

you can always try:

1.take a screen grab to get the font into a bitmap.
2.In `Photoshop` remove any extraneous artifacts
3. go to [what the font](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)
4. upload and follow the online steps to help the site recognize the letters
5. It will output the fonts the text you uploaded resembles.

Have fun designing with your newly found favorite font.

Comment: Definitely not Century Gothic. There are commonalities with Trade Gothic Extended and Neogram, but it's not either of those.

Comment: True.. possibly it's time for me to knock the dust off the old typography book again. lol

Answer (score 5):

The closest match I could find is [Bryant](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/processtype/bryant/), but there are some subtle differences, particularly in the letters K and E and in the shapes of the numbers (which look very close but not quite the same).  Of course, the "RO" part of the logo is obviously custom, so it's hard to say how much the rest might have been tweaked as well.

[image]